# Parsing a userstring data in files present in directories

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to do the following ,it fails to match even a good case,sample input file and the complete code is given below?why is the code not matching the sample input file below?how to overcome it?

1.Open each file in the directory and subdirectories based on the argument(whic

2.Check if each file has the copyright info exactly the 3 lines,these 3 lines doesnt have to be starting 3 lines

```
 Copyright (c) 2012 Company, Inc. 
 All Rights Reserved.
 Company Confidential and Proprietary.
```

Sample input file:-

```
File1.txt

/*==========================================================================
 *
 *  @file:     Compiler.h
 *
 *  @brief:    This file 
 *
 *
 *  @author:   david
 *
 *  Copyright (c) 2012 Company, Inc. 
 *  All Rights Reserved.
 *  Company Confidential and Proprietary
 *
 *=========================================================================*/
#ifndef __COMPILER_ABSTRACT_H
#define __COMPILER_ABSTRACT_H
```

The code:

```
import os
import sys
userstring="Copyright (c) 2012 Company, Inc.\nAll Rights Reserved.\nCompany Confidential and Proprietary."
print len(sys.argv)
print sys.argv[1]
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    sys.exit('Usage: python.py <build directory>')
for r,d,f in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    for files in f:
        with open(os.path.join(r, files), "r") as file:
            if ''.join(file.readlines()[:3]).strip() != userstring:
                print files
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what `''.join(file.readlines()[:3]).strip()` gives you. You'll notice the `*` between the lines are still there, and you will get the first 3 lines (`[:3]` does that), which is certainly not what you want in the example file. While they are not in the `userstring`.

One possible solution would be to check each line on its own. Something like this:

```
userlines = userstring.split('\n') # Separate the string into lines
with open(os.path.join(r, files), "r") as file:
    match = 0
    for line in file:
        if userlines[match] in line: # Check if the line at index `m` is in the user lines
            match += 1 # Next time check the following line
        elif match > 0: # If there was no match, reset the counter
            match = 0
        if match >= len(userlines): # If 3 consecutive lines match, then you found a match
            break
    if match == len(userlines): # You found a match
        print files
```

The idea behind this is that what you are looking for is not an exact match because there are blank lines, `*`, dots, whitespace, etc. I used the `in` operator to account more or less for this, but you could come up with something much more flexible when you work on a per line basis. Even more when you are working with files...

**UPDATE**:

For more advanced parsing on each line, you could make use of regular expressions using the `re` package, but that might not be practical in your use case, because you mostly want to match a string more than a pattern. So to ignore the last character, you could try removing/ignoring any (whitespace or dots or stars) in the beginning or end.

For example:

```
>>> a = '   This is a string.   '
>>> a.strip()
'This is a string.' # removes the whitespace by default
>>> a.strip('.')
'   This is a string.   ' # removes only dots
>>> a.strip('. ')
'This is a string' # removes dots and spaces
```

To make it match with your input and the `userstring` I'd suggest you process both strings in the same way (i.e. remove the spaces/dots from both), unless you are sure of what you have in `userstring`. With modifications you should have something like that:

```
userlines = [s.strip('\n\r .') for s in userstring.split('\n')]
# ...
        if userlines[match] == line.strip('\n\r .'):
# ...
```

Once you process your file on a per-line basis, you can make use of lots of useful functions like `startswith`, `endswith`, `strip`, `count`, `find`, ... Just type `help(str)` in an interpreter for a complete list.

Comment: Thanks,thats really useful,how can I make the period "." before the newline ("\n")characer as optional in userstring="Copyright (c) 2012 Company, Inc.\nAll Rights Reserved.\nCompany Confidential and Proprietary."

Comment: @user1927233 Check my update, I hope it answers your question :)